# Debug console prints convoluted text

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

When I run my program in the VS Code debugger, the output in the debugger console is unintelligible. It always looks like this:

[image: VS Code Debug console for c#]

The texts are so jumbled that I can't even copy anything. It appears that the lines (rows) of text are overlapping each other.

Comment: Please clarify: is that a screen shot of the IDE itself? Or of the window for a program you wrote using the IDE? Either way, it looks like the font setting has gotten corrupted somehow. If it doesn't go away after rebooting the machine, you might have to try reinstalling the IDE.

Comment: It's the screenshot of IDE itself. I'll go for reinstalling of IDE and see if it works. 

This comes in the debug console when I click run for the .net project.

Comment: I haven't used VS Code, but if it's anything like VS, there are settings in the program where you can configure fonts for various windows/panes. So one thing you might check before you reinstall is to see if you can find the font setting for that particular pane and check whether it needs to be changed to something else.

Comment: Thank you @PeterDuniho 
I found a setting for Features > debug in VS Code, and the line-height was set to 2. Changing this to 16 corrected the issue.

Comment: Great. You can help the Stack Overflow community by posting an answer below describing what you did. Screen shots showing how to get to the setting would add to the usefulness of an answer. Then self-accept the answer (i.e. click the "check" mark) so that it's clear to others you've resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and just figured it out on my end.

It was because I had the `"debug.console.lineHeight": 2` setting extremely low (*literally had it at 2 >.<*)

I changed it to something slightly larger than the font size (*15 font & 18 lineHight worked well for me*).

Hope this helps!